# Xpath Get text after only first html tag

Tags: python, html, xpath

There are next block

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Headerh1</h1>
   Text1 <br/> after header1 
  <h3>Headerh3.1</h3> 
     Text2 <br/> after header3.1 
  <h3>Headerh3.2</h3>
    Text3 <br/> after header3.2 
  <h3>Headerh3.3</h3>
    Text4 <br/> after header3.3 
</div>
```

How to get text after first H1 with ignore `<br/><br/>` as
"Text1 after header1"
`//div[@class='text']/text()[count(preceding-sibling::h1)=1]` return text after all headers.
`<br>` can be 0+ times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below XPath that should return all text nodes of `div` that located right before the first `h3`:

```
//div[@class='text']/h3[1]/preceding-sibling::text()
```

Comment: It works, but if will be text after div, it will be returned too.Is it possible to add condition text between h3 but after h1?

Comment: Yes. This one should do the trick `//div[@class='text']/h3[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[./preceding-sibling::h1]`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is a html in your directory and it's called 
demo.html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("demo.html") as f:
    data = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    f.close()

#to get the text after h1 tag
 h1 = soup.find('h1').text
#to get the text after all h3 tags
 h3 = [i.text for i in soup.findAll('h3')]
```

the outputs will be in unicode format
for eg:

```
h3 = [u'Headerh3.1', u'Headerh3.2', u'Headerh3.3']
```

to convert them into normal strings do this

```
h3 = [i.text.encode('utf-8') for i in soup.findAll('h3')]
h1 = soup.find('h1').text.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I need to get text between headers h1, h3 "Text1 <br/> after header1 "